# The code only displays False, Can anyone explain to me what's wrong with it

Tags: java, arrays, string-comparison

// trying to find whether two string match after toUppercase operation

```
package testapp1;

public class TestApp1 
{
    public static void main(String[] performing_a_simple_for_loop)
    {
        String firstName = "John";
        char fname[] = {'J','O','H','N'};
        System.out.println(firstName.toUpperCase());
        String name2;
        name2 = firstName.toUpperCase();
        if(fname.equals(name2))
        {
            System.out.println("True");    
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because char[] is diferent to String. Try using: new String(fname).equals(name2).

Comment: Because `char[]` is an array of characters and `String` is a class, they are not the same. You should cast the characters array to a `String` and then compare it to another `String`. As other already mentioned: `new String(fname).equals(name2);`

Answer (score 2):

`fname` is an array, so can not be directly compared to a String

You can do

```
if(new String(fname).equals(name2))
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the reason why is always printing `false`

```
fname.equals(name2)
```

you are comparing a String against an array...

that return false because they are not the same data type

imagine if I do:

```
"1".equals(1)
```

yes, both are holding somehow the same information, but that is not enough in java to say they are equal...

---

so what you can do:??? you need to convert one type into the other...

```
// option 1: char[] -> string
System.out.println(new String(fname).equals(firstName.toUpperCase()));

// option 2: string -> char[]
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(firstName.toUpperCase().toCharArray(), fname));
```

and as you see, for comparing arrays you may need the [Array.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-char:A-char:A-) method